# Selecting records from 2 Mysql tables using intermediary table

Tags: mysql

I have 4 mysql tables as follows:

```
products:
----------------------------------------------------
product_id    product_name   price    discount
----------------------------------------------------
1             product 1      10.00       1.00
2             product 2      20.00       2.00
3             product 3      25.00       1.00
----------------------------------------------------

subcategory

----------------------------------------------------
subcategory_id    subcategory_name       status
----------------------------------------------------
1                 subcat 1               Enabled
2                 subcat 2               Disabled
3                 subcat 3               Enabled
------------------------------------------------------

temp_products
------------------------------------------------------
id               productid               catid
------------------------------------------------------
1                   1                      1
2                   1                      2
3                   2                      1
------------------------------------------------------


product_images
------------------------------------------------------
product_id             images
------------------------------------------------------
   1                    image1.jpg
   1                    image2.jpg
   2                    image2-1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------
```

temp_products.catid and subcategory.subcategory_id

and

temp_products.productid and products.product_id

and

products.product_id and product_images.product_id

are related..

Multiple products can come under a subcategory.

I wish to have a subcategory selected with all products with 1 image (first image) coming under it and WHERE subcategory.status is "Enabled"...?? (LIMIT 1)

How can I choose it in Random too...??? (RAND)

I need to get result like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
subcategory_id   subcategory_name product_id  product_name, price, discount, images
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1              subcat 1           1        product 1    10.00   1.00    image1.jpg
     1              subcat 1           2        product 2    20.00   2.00    image2- 1.jpg
```

Hope somebody can assist me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This untested query should give you the result:

```
Select * from subcategory  join temp_products  on temp_products.catid = subcategory.subcategory_id join products  on temp_products.productid = products.product_id where subcategory.status='Enabled'
```

Buzt I do not unstand what this part "How can I choose it in Random too...??? (RAND)" of your question means.

Comment: I wish to select a subcategory and its associated products in random from the multiple rows available..

Comment: @user3790186 Sorry copy/paste error. i have edited my answer.

Comment: @user3790186 Add an example for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products.*, (SELECT subcategory.id FROM subcategory WHERE `status` = enabled ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as sub 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN temp_products ON products.products_id = temp_products.productid
INNER JOIN subcategory ON temp_products.catid = subcategory = subcategory_id
WHERE temp_products.catid = sub
```

Try this

Comment: Sorry, it is not working, even after correcting errors in query provided..unknown column 'sub' in WHERE clause